# Cancelled AsyncTask hangs new HttpRequests

Tags: android, httprequest, android-asynctask

I'm having problem with asynctasks and http requests.

The user can press two different buttons. Both buttons download information from a web server. I want the requests to be cancelable. Before each call a progressdialog is shown.

The http request is performed in an asynctask, and I have an OnDismiss listener on the progressdialog that cancels the asynctask if back is pressed.

It works 50/50.

If I do the http request, cancel the asynctask, then do a new request, it might work but it might also cause the http request to hang infinite.

This line is where it hangs:

`response = httpclient.execute(urlConnection, context);`

Is there any other way to do a call that is cancelable or is there anything I could do to avoid the hang?

Comment: here is an example on how to cancel an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an `AsyncTask` to perform some downloads over http, and I found that calling `cancel()` on the task doesn't actually stop the task from executing.  The "cancelled" task will continue to perform its background actions.  Calling `cancel()` just seemed to call `onCancelled()` and then the `AsyncTask` *doesn't* call `onPostExecute()` when it has finished.  Perhaps your first task still has hold of some network resource that the next task requires?

Comment: Thanks! This turned me in the right direction. I never thought of the `onCancelled()`. So I tried to close the connectionmanager in the `onCancelled()` and restart it directly again, and it to works.  Maybe not the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

```
httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```